# If A ("whole") has a set of Bs ("parts"), how to synchronize the transfer of a "part" B from a "whole" A to another?

Tags: c++, oop, synchronization

Suppose we have whole-part object relationship. For instance, there is a `Boss` that can own multiple `Worker`s.
For a `Boss`, we want the following operations:

- add a new `Worker` to its "collection"
- transfer an existing `Worker` object to another `Boss` object

I provide some C++ code that illustrates this idea below (some functions were skipped).

```
class Worker {
private:
    Boss *owner = nullptr;
    std::string name;

public:
    Worker(std::string name) : name(name), owner(nullptr) { }

    Boss* getOwner() const {
        return this->owner;
    }

    void setOwner(Boss *owner) {
        this->owner = owner;
    }
};

class Boss {
private:
    std::set<Worker *> workers;
    std::string name;

public:
    Boss(std::string name) : name(name) { }

    ~Boss() {
        for (auto worker : this->workers) {
            delete worker;
        }
        this->workers.clear();
    }

    void addWorker(Worker *worker) {
        this->workers.emplace(worker);
        worker->setOwner(this);
    }

    void transferOwnership(Worker *dummyWorker, Boss *newOwner);
};

int main()
{
    Boss b1{ "boss1" };
    Boss b2{ "boss2" };

    b1.addWorker(new Worker{ "w1" });
    b1.addWorker(new Worker{ "w2" });

    b2.addWorker(new Worker{ "w3" });

    Worker temp{ "w2" };
    b1.transferOwnership(&temp, &b2);

    b1.print(); // boss: boss1 having workers: w1
    b2.print(); // boss: boss2 having workers: w2 w3

    return 0;
}
```

A **serial** implementation of the `transferOwnership()` function would be the following:

```
void Boss::transferOwnership(Worker *dummyWorker, Boss *newOwner) {
    // find existing worker
    Worker *actualWorker = nullptr;
    for (auto worker : this->workers) {
        if (*worker == *dummyWorker) {
            actualWorker = worker;
        }
    }

    if (nullptr == actualWorker) {
        return;
    }

    // remove existing worker from this
    this->workers.erase(actualWorker);

    // add worker to other (newOwner)
    newOwner->workers.emplace(actualWorker);
    actualWorker->setOwner(newOwner);
}
```

Now, we want to parallelize this scenario. Suppose there are multiple threads that can execute any of the available operations (`addWorker()` or `transferOwnership()`) on any of the existing `Boss` objects.

The question is how to synchronize the code such that we always get a consistent result at the end and not get into deadlocks.

I think a solution would be to have a static mutex variable inside the `Boss` class, lock it at the beginning of the operation and end it at the end. This will protect all `workers` sets of all `Boss` objects.

Another solution would be to have a mutex for each `Boss` object. However, I think here we might encounter deadlocks as in `transferOwnership()` we will need to lock/unlock the mutexes of both `Boss`es and I think we cannot impose a certain locking order in this situation.

Can you think of other/better solutions?

Comment: You have answered your own question in the last two paragraphs of your question. So, what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/5429653/6296561 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static mutex solution works. However, if you do want to have a mutex for each object, then your transaction requires locking of 2 bosses and 1 worker (depending on your requirements you may need to lock only the 2 boss objects).

In order to avoid deadlocks in this scenario, simply implement a function that locks the 3 mutexes according to some well-known pre-defined order. Their location in memory may serve for that purpose.

Your function would look like:

1. sort the 2 or 3 mutexes according to their memory address
2. lock them according to that order (make sure that you don't get the same mutex twice)

If you're on C++11 you can just use the `std::lock(std::mutex... mutexes)` that does more or less the same thing.

```
void lock(std::mutex& m1, std::mutex& m2) {
  if (&m1==&m2)
    m1.lock();
  else if (&m1<&m2) {
    m1.lock();
    m2.lock();
  } else {
    m2.lock();
    m1.lock();
  }
}
```

Unlocking is done in reverse order.